# How to best handle different type of users (rails 3.2/devise/heroku)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, devise, cancan

I am creating a daily deal app.

I am using devise for authentication (sign up/sign in).

I need to have multiple types of users that are not independent but each have a little more "right"s according to the sign up step he is in:

- guest user: lowest rights: It's basically just standard visitors visiting the website (but I create an account as soon as they come in order if they sign up to have their history)
- user_with_only_email: I changed devise so that users can sign up only by giving their email( no password on the very first step of the sign up process).
- user_with_email_and_password: these users have provided password and password confirmation in the 2nd step of the sign up process
- confirmed_users: users with email, password and who have confirmed their subscription by clicking on the confirmation email link.

I am using Cancan and Rolify already as I have used the roles: User, Admin, superadmin

I wonder if Cancan and Rolify are well suited for me to implement theses other users roles, given that they are not independent but allow users to have gradual rights. Indeed, I want to be able to say that this page can only be seen starting from the user_with_only_email meaning that all the roles above (user_with_email_and_password and confirmed_users will then of course have access to this page)

Would you say that CanCan and Rolify is made for this and fits my needs? Maybe there are other better tools for this?

Comment: See your other question for my suggestion. There is no need to create a role just to set authorization rules. What you should do is check those states as you define your authorization rules: role: `confirmed_users` becomes `if user.confirmed?`.

Comment: @Damien thanks. i'm gonna implement users with sign up with only email (here: github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Email-only-sign-up) . How do i access them: user.sign up?